# Why does mypy raise truthy-function error for assertion?

Tags: python, mypy

I inherited a project from a dev who is no longer at the company.
He wrote this test:

```
from contextlib import nullcontext as does_not_raise


def test_validation_raised_no_error_when_validation_succeeds():
    # given
    given_df = DataFrame(data={"foo": [1, 2], "bar": ["a", "b"]})
    given_schema = Schema(
        [
            Column("foo", [InListValidation([1, 2])]),
            Column("bar", [InListValidation(["a", "b"])]),
        ]
    )
    # when
    _validate_schema(given_df, given_schema)

    # then
    assert does_not_raise  # line 251
```

This project has mypy configured and it complains about the assertion:

```
test/clients/test_my_client.py:251: error: Function "Type[nullcontext[Any]]" could always be true in boolean context  [truthy-function]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 24 source files)
```

I don't understand what the problem is.
[The documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_code_list2.html?highlight=truthy#check-that-function-isn-t-used-in-boolean-context-truthy-function) doesn't provide any meaningful advice.
I can disable the check like this:

```
assert does_not_raise  # type: ignore
```

but I'd rather understand the problem and address it properly.

For reference, here is the mypy config:

```
[mypy]
python_version = 3.8
warn_return_any = True
warn_unused_configs = True
ignore_missing_imports = True
```

Comment: that assertion will always be true (just as the mypy error message suggested), so it doesn't make any sense

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga *All* assertions will always be true (unless you screwed up somewhere). That's why you assert them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test intends to check that the `# given` and `# when` parts of the test case run without raising any exception. The `# then` part is probably only there to satisfy the given-when-then pattern. As mypy says, the line doesn't do anything, it is functionally equivalent to `assert bool(some_existing_function_name)` which is equivalent to `assert True`, which is functionally equivalent to just having a comment.

Note that `does_not_raise` is a function, but it's not called. Just naming a function in an `assert` (or `if`) always returns True.

You can keep silencing the mypy warning as you do now, replace it with `assert True`, `assert "if this line runs, the previous parts didn't raise any exception"`, or just a comment – they will all be functionally equivalent.

Comment: Great and coherent answer! Thank you very much <3